# Jquery Validation Engine issue

Tags: jquery-validation-engine

I am using the following jquery validation engine:
http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/index.html   - version 2.6.2

When i refer to the existing solutions and try to apply, it dose not workout the way as expected.

if i give in the following in script:

```
function isActorSelected(field, rules, i, options){
    if ($('#actor').is(':checked') && field.val() == '') {
         console.log("Condition is true");
        return options.allrules.validate2fields.alertText;
    }
}
```

and the following in HTML

```
<td><input name="languages_know" id="languages_known" type="text" size="50" class="validate[funcCall[isActorSelected]]" /></td>
```

what i expect is an alertbox showing up the message. But unfortunately - it dose not show any message.
Also, 1 thing for sure .. the condition is getting executed properly as i am able to see the message in console.log

Can any 1 please help on this as how to proceed with the same?